# Декларация типа композиции функций

Tags: haskell, функциональное-программирование

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Как правильно читается декларация типа композиции функций?

Comment: Не очень понятна суть вопроса. Что конкретно Вам неясно в этой декларации?

Comment: Мне не до конца понятно, что и за что отвечает в данной декларации. А в частности как работает функция композиции, исходя из данной декларации, пошагово.

Comment: Ну, по сути - читается справа на лево. "с" - результат, "а" - параметр, (a->b) - первая функция, применяется к параметру, (b->c) - вторая функция, применяется к результату работы первой и формирует окончательный результат. А вообще - в самой декларации все четко прописано по типам: a - параметр первой функции, b -  результат первой функции и параметр второй, c - результат второй функции и, соответственно, результат их композиции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для лучшего восприятия, можно добавить в сигнатуру лишние скобки.

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
```

В данном случае это не влияет на результат, так как `->` – правоассоциативный оператор, а значит одинаковые операции и так группируются справа налево, и следующие сигнатуры полностью идентичны:

```
a -> b -> c -> d
a -> b -> (c -> d)
a -> (b -> c -> d)
a -> (b -> (c -> d))
```

В итоге получаем:

> `(.)` принимает функцию из `b` в `с`, функцию из `a` в `b` и возвращает функцию из `a` в `с`

А вот для того, чтобы понять как этот оператор мог бы быть реализован, скобки лучше наоборот убрать.

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

> `(.)` принимает функцию из `b` в `с`, функцию из `a` в `b`, аргумент типа `a` и возвращает результат типа `c`

Благодаря параметричности, существует всего одна сходящаяся реализация:

> Чтобы получить значение типа `c`, нужно применить первую функцию `b -> c` к значению типа `b`, которое можно получить, применив вторую функцию `a -> b` к аргументу типа `a`

Т.е. реализация может быть одной из следующих (эквавалентных)

```
(.) f g x = f (g x)
```

```
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

```
(f . g) x = f (g x)
```